# Strange formula string seeing in my existing project

Tags: formula

In my existing project, I found this similar piece of code appeared many times:

```
DATE(YEAR( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) ), MONTH(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate )), DAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate ) )) >= DATE(2015,10,27)
```

Personally, I find it really strange and think it should definitely just be:

```
DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) >= DATE(2015,10,27)
```

Any reason to use the existing logic? I can't think of any but I just want to be cautious.

Comment: This formula was likely written by an administrator or a newbie developer. There's absolutely no reason for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is more optimized and will return the same result.

```
DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) >= DATE(2015,10,27)
```

You are not sure about the impact then create a new formula field with this and then use it for testing. After all sorts of testing like, record details, list views, reports etc with this new field, then delete this new field and replace the old field logic with your formula.